# Usb Mouse not working in Ubuntu Ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, usb, mouse

Recently I am facing problem with my USB mouse. Sometimes it works sometimes it not works with a reboot. A result of `lsusb` is below :

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011  Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2805 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The second line shows my mouse name but when I move the mouse the cursor does not move.
If any other thing is needed, I will edit my question.